# python pandas create dataframe based on dynamic calculation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dynamic

I have two dataframes and want to create a third one based on dynamic calculations.

df1 (have)

```
prod time value
A    1    10
A    2    20
A    3    30
B    1    15
B    2    20
B    3    80
```

df2 (have)

```
prod time1 time2 new_name
A    1     3    'newval'
B    1     2    'newval'
A    1     2    'newval2'
B    1     3    'newval2'
```

df3(want)

```
prod value_newval value_newval2 
A    -20            -10
B    -5             -65
```

Want to create df3 in an efficient way. Each record in df2 indicates how to calculate df3 (i.e. for prod A, subtract value time=1 and time=3 from df1 and name this column as value(df1)_new_name(df2), for prod B, subtract time=1 and time=2 etc.)

Currently I am able to create this by going line by line through df2 and creating multiple subsets of df1 and eventually concatenating them but this is taking a long time given df1 can get very large

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `melt` then `merge` + `groupby`

```
df2.drop('new_name',1).melt('prod',value_name='time').\
      merge(df1,how='left').groupby('prod').value.apply(lambda x : x.iloc[0]-x.iloc[1])
Out[177]: 
prod
A   -20
B    -5
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

---

Update

```
df2.melt(['prod','new_name'],value_name='time').\
      merge(df1,how='left').groupby(['prod','new_name']).value.apply(lambda x : x.iloc[0]-x.iloc[1]).unstack()
Out[205]: 
new_name  'newval'  'newval2'
prod                         
A              -20        -10
B               -5        -65
```

Comment: could this be updated to include additional records in df2? edited question